# How to send post form data through a http client?

Tags: http, go, http-post

I have a problem with post request, needed to send simple form data through http client.
http.PostForm() is not ok because I need to set my own user agent and other headers.

Here is the sample

```
func main() {
    formData := url.Values{
        "form1": {"value1"},
        "form2": {"value2"},
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    
    //Not working, the post data is not a form
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://test.local/api.php", strings.NewReader(formData.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Golang_Super_Bot/0.1")
    
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which corresponds to the encoding used by [`Value.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode).

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

This is mentioned as one of the things done by [Client.PostForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm).